# View all records which exist in associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Goal:**
I want to show all Category that are currently in existence in the Listing model.

For instance, a Listing can have many categories.  Say I have 100 categories and 10 listings but only 20 of those categories are currently being used in the Listing.category_ids, I only want those to appear.

**I have tried:**

```
@categories = Category.all.where(id: @listings.each {|listing| listing.category_ids})

@categories = Category.where(id: Listing.all.includes(:category_ids)).order(name: :asc)

@categories = Category.where(id: [@listings.each {|listing| listing.category_ids}])
```

And some other similar ways.  BTW, i use Postgres.

Both of these attempts have only appeared the first category within the Category model, even though that category isn't being used.

Models:

Listing

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

Categories:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :listings
```

I then have a Categories_Listings join table too t for it all.  That is where the associations are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a join for that. Try

```
Category.joins(:listings)
```

In this way you should see just rows which have a match in listings

Comment: I suggest studying a bit of SQL if you are interested in writing good active record's queries

Comment: What way can I make it so only 1 copy of the category appears?  For instance, if 2 listings use the same category, it's appearing twice

Comment: Looks like `.distinct` does the job.  Is that the best way in your ways?